# path of myapp.ini in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

My program is creating an .ini  file via:

```
def build_config(self, config):

        config.setdefaults('kategory', {
            'option1': 'value1',
            'option2': 'value2'
            })
```

Recently I added the option that I only have to double-click on a pickle-file to import it in my program using the `sys.argv` parameters.

If I open a file via double-click the `.ini` file will automatically created next to the opened file.
Every time I open a file via double I will leave a `.ini` file in the directory.

Is there a way to set the path of the `.ini` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`App.get_application.config()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_application_config) is the method you want. It should give you the same path as it [uses](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/5913d861f45119dfff0b6cb5d004e6f79858563c/kivy/app.py#L700) the method during creation of the config in `build_config()`. To **set** it, however, you'll need to override the default method in your app class e.g.:

```
class Test(App):
    def get_application_config(self, defaultpath=your_path):
        if platform == 'android':
            defaultpath = '/sdcard/.%(appname)s.ini'
        elif platform == 'ios':
            defaultpath = '~/Documents/%(appname)s.ini'
        elif platform == 'win':
            defaultpath = defaultpath.replace('/', sep)
        return expanduser(defaultpath) % {
            'appname': self.name, 'appdir': self.directory}
```

or maybe some magic with `super()` in a similar way could make it look more eye-pleasant, though I'm afraid it could go recursive or throw other lovely errors.

Answer (score 1):

This version has been tested on Windows 10 and Android. The version above does not compile as is and requires further research whose result is here.

```
def get_application_config(self, defaultpath="c:/temp/%(appname)s.ini"):
    from kivy.utils import platform
    from os.path import sep, expanduser

    if platform == 'android':
        defaultpath = '/sdcard/.%(appname)s.ini'
    elif platform == 'ios':
        defaultpath = '~/Documents/%(appname)s.ini'
    elif platform == 'win':
        defaultpath = defaultpath.replace('/', sep)

    return os.path.expanduser(defaultpath) % {
        'appname': self.name, 'appdir': self.directory}
```